# Default Queues for Disabled users in CRM 2011 - can they be deleted with confidence?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

On-Premise CRM 2011 installation with a number of disabled users. Has anyone deleted the default queue for these users?  What risks or adverse behavior can I expect?  Primary interest is in cleaning up the list of queues -- Inactivating queues does not accomplish this. My own smoke testing has uncovered no negative side effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen any undesirable or odd side effects of deleting default queues of users or Teams, but of course if you have an entity which is ticked to say "add to default queue when record is reassigned" then this would fail for any user or team without one (I'm not sure iif this would also means the assign action fails/rolls back).

Deleting them for deactivated users would of course not have this issue since they can't have records assigned to them.

You probably want to do an Advanced Find of Queue Items first to check there are none still in any Queue owned by an inactive user.

Comment: :Then do I understand correctly that even in cases when I delete the default queue for a user that I have the opportunity to create another default queue for that user in the future?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure you can't. You are talking about re-activating a user and creating a new Queue for them, but it won't be recognised as their "default" Queue.
If you are concerned about needing to do this, then deactivate the Queues rather than deleting them completely.

Comment: Also note: I checked and you can assign a record to someone who has no default Queue and the assign works but does not create any Queue item.

Comment: your most recent comment is consistent with my experience and testing.  And my interest is in the sizable number of "dead queues" that stack up.  My preference would be to deactivate.  My experience is that deactivating a queue does not seem to remove it from the drop down.

Comment: It does appear that on the User record that you have the option to set that users' default queue.  Presumably this could be an existing queue or one that was recently created.  This, to me, answers my original question. Can I delete (default) Queues for users that are disabled.  Then later if the user is reactivated a new queue be created and assigned to be their default queue.